# Passing a Contact Form 7 Value to another Form in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have a contact form on my website, which saves information to our Contact Form Database. I also need this data to be passed on to another form.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column small-12 medium-6">[text* first-name placeholder "First Name*"]</div>
<div class="column small-12 medium-6">[text* last-name placeholder "Last Name*"]</div>
<div class="column small-12 medium-6">[email* email placeholder "Email*"]</div>
<div class="column small-12 medium-6">[text* phone placeholder "Phone*"]</div>
<div class="column checking"><span class="intro">Preferred method of contact*</span> [checkbox* checkbox use_label_element "Email" "Phone"]</div>
<div class="column small-12">[textarea* enquiry placeholder "Further Info"]</div>
<div class="column text-center"><button type="submit" class="button">Send Enquiry</button></div>
</div>
```

I need First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone and Enquiry placeholder information passed into the following form.

```
<form id="form" action="http:www.contoso.com.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="FirstName" value="first-name"/>
<input type="hidden" name="LastName" value="last-name"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Email" value="email"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Mobile" value="phone"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Comment" value="enquiry"/>
```

How do I get the information from the first form into the second through Contact Form 7 in Wordpress?

I thought this might work in the additional settings page of CF7, but my coding knowledge is quite low:

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').value = document.getElementById('first-name').value;
document.getElementById('LastName').value = document.getElementById('last-name').value;
document.getElementById('Email').value = document.getElementById('email').value;
document.getElementById('Mobile').value = document.getElementById('phone').value;
document.getElementById('Comment').value = document.getElementById('enquiry').value;
on_submit: "document.forms['form'].submit();"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another logic to achieve your goal.
1) create a very basic table in your sites database:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_cf7_test(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

2) Next up log into your wordpress sites administration area and open up the Contact Form 7 form editor and again create a very simple form like so:

```
[text* name]
[submit "Send"]
```

After you have done that open up your sites functions.php file and create the following function, which should be relatively self explanatory, initialize the $wpdb global variable which we will use to fire off the insert query. then you assign the WPCF7_Submission::get_instance() method to a variable and access whatever parts of the posted array you need or in this case its just one item called “name” which is what our forms input field is called. Finally you execute the insert function that will send your data to the table created earlier. :

```
<?php 
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) 
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
    $name = $formData['name'];

    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_cf7_test', array( 'name' =>; $name ), array( '%s' ) );
}
remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'contactform7_before_send_mail' );
```

Finally Get the values of Contactform7  into any other table which you want.